# Updating a backgroundcolor based on input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have input which contain a hexColor. every time this input is changed i would like to update the background color on a specific div, so far i've added following javascript code, which get this value from the input. What do i need to make it keep updating the background color on the div with the id `NavBar`

```
var navBar = document.getElementById("navBarColor").value;
```

Comment: Better to use color-picker and update div background color on change of selected color.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating backgroundColor LIVE based upon an input field value using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948524/updating-backgroundcolor-live-based-upon-an-input-field-value-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with this DEMO.

```
$(function() {
    var bgColor = $('#colorpickerField1').val();   
    $('body').css("backgroundColor",'#' + bgColor);

    $('#colorpickerField1').keyup(function() {
       $('body').css("backgroundColor",'#' + $(this).val());
    });
});
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/AHZBT/) //by color code

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gaurangnil/AHZBT/3/) //by color name